# Eigenvectors of Matrix Product Operator (MPO)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, tensor-calculus, quantum-entanglement, tensor-network

I am starting to work with tensor network and I wanted to know how to get the eigenvectors of a [Matrix Product Operator](https://tensornetwork.org/mpo/) (MPO).

As far as I know when one is trying to diagonalize his Hamiltonian he needs to specify the indices how to truncate the Hamiltonian, and my question is how to choose the right and left indices?

I will try to give some example:

Suppose that I have a MPO that acts on a three site system (spin half sites) , which are labelled by i, j, k (those are the physical indices) and 2 bond dimension l, m (those are the link indices).

Now, my MPO will have 6 physical indices $(i,j,k,i',j',k') +$ 4 link indices $(l,m,l',m')$.

When I will diagonalize them I will something like:
$$H_{i,j,k,i',j',k'}^{l,m,l',m'}=U_{i,j,k}^{l,a}D_{a,a'}^{mm'}(U_{i',j',k'}^{l',a'})^{-1} $$
This is just one possibility for how to separate the indices.

So, I want to know how to determine how to separate the indices in such a way that I will get the eigenvectors of that MPO.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear.

Comment: Is this of any help: [Diagonalizing transfer matrices and matrix product operators: a medley of exact and computational methods](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.08519)?